Is there a way to isolate 2 operating systems on 2 different hard drives?
I have a computer with 2 operating systems installed on 2 separate hard drives.
I would like to know if it's possible to completely isolate them, meaning that one operating system shouldn't be able to see or access the other hard drive.
I use one operating system for work and another for leisure and would like to keep both environments separate.
Is there a way to achieve this without physically disconnecting the hard drive that is not in use? Both operating systems installed on the hard drives are Windows 10.

BitLocker and just not decrypting the drive seems like a reasonable compromise

@Ramhound That sounds pretty good, does encryption have any impact on hard drive performance?

@JoanLara - No; The drive is unware it’s encrypted. All encryption is done within the kernel itself.  The only connection would be the EFI partition, it would need to be aware, of both drives to boot into Windows. Decryption of the secondary drive would be something you choose to do though

That en/decryption is done by the kernel doesn't prove that there is no performance penalty, @Ramhound. The benchmarks I've seen have shown that there is, indeed, a performance impact by enabling BitLocker.

1/2 While there are methods (encryption, virtualization, etc) to increase the barriers between 2 OSes running on the same computer, so long as the drive for the unused OS is present and active in the running OS, there is a chance of that drive being manipulated. There is a principle of computer security that states that physical access IS access: if an attacker has physical access to a computer, for any length of time, there is a chance the computer is irrevocably compromised. You must use the same mindset when dealing with system isolation.

2/2 You must decide what your safety margin is, what the actual requirements and security rules require. Every security decision is a trade-off between usability and security. The most perfectly secure computer is powered off, air gapped, fully isolated in every way and incapable of even responding to any potential threat. That is, obviously, an unusable computer. The most convenient computer is the least secure. So, the phrase "complete isolation" is unrealistic. Instead, define the level of acceptable isolation, and then make decisions and configure based on that decision.

"does encryption have any impact on hard drive performance?"  If your worried about the speed of your disks then upgrade to SSD or NVMe instead of a hard drive.  Yes, encryption adds a small amount of additional CPU work.

Depending upon the BIOS, you may have the option to enable/disable specific ports.
Looking at the example  of a HP Z4 G4, the BIOS allows individual SATA or M.2 ports to be disabled:

HP also provide the HP BIOS Configuration Utility (BCU) which allows a administrator shell under Windows to get and set individual BIOS settings. E.g. reading the current state of the SATA0 port being enabled:
C:\SWSetup\SP143621>BiosConfigUtility.exe /getvalue:SATA0
<BIOSCONFIG Version="" Computername="COMPUTERNAME" Date="2024/08/31" Time="18:12:47" UTC="1">
        <SETTING changeStatus="pass" name = "SATA0" returnCode="0">
                <VALUE><![CDATA[Disable,*Enable,eSATA]]></VALUE>
        </SETTING>
        <SUCCESS msg="No errors occurred" />
        <Information msg="BCU return value" real="0" translated="0" />
</BIOSCONFIG>

So, depending upon the BIOS you may be able to create a script to run in one Windows operating system which could disable the port for one disk and enable the port for a different disk, to change the selection on the next boot.
